# BigCommerce Stencil: is it possible to get higher quality images from the CDN helper or bypass it everywhere?

Tags: bigcommerce

I've noticed that BigCommerce's CDN helper massively reduces the image quality of the images that we pass to it. This is especially problematic on the zoomed-in image on product view pages. I provide a high quality 2000px x 2000px image, and it returns a very pixelated image with the same dimensions. Zooming in on such an image is very off putting and I'd sooner disable zooming that go forward with this.

Has anyone discovered a good work around for this or a way to disable BC's image quality impairment? I thought I had a good workaround that involved ripping out CDN helper references and pointing to images on our own CDN (file names based on SKU), but discovered that this can't be done on the checkout (probably abandoned cart emails too) and doesn't work on images that are inserted by Javascript, for example when one product has two styles (different skus).

I've been customizing the Cornerstone theme in Stencil for my employer for about a month and BigCommerce hasn't been able to provide direction on this issue.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of a product with a large, high-res image that's returning a blurry image? It would be good to take a look and see if we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: I've pasted a screenshot but this store isn't public yet. Have you worked with Stencil before?

Comment: Yes, I'm a developer advocate at BigCommerce. We wouldn't consider it intended behavior for images to appear blurry and pixelated, but I'd need to take a look at your store to really see what's going on. If you could email me at karen.white@bigcommerce.com with your store URL or a case number, I'd be happy to look into it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we were actually providing a 500px image and asking Stencil to display a 2000px image for the zoomed image, so this result makes sense.